# K-means clustering with constraints

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, cluster-analysis, k-means

The context is as follows:

I am tasked to re-cluster a vending machine company's vending machine routes (they're more so areas that each serviceman is responsible for).

I have geocoded the lon/lat values for each vending machine and have used basic k-means clustering to find the most "mathematically sound" clusters.

However, I have to ensure that each cluster meets the following criteria:

1. each cluster should have a similar number of vending machines
2. the total sales for each cluster should also be about the same

I'm pretty new to R and adapted code from ChatGPT to accomplish this thus far.

My current code is as follows:

```
    # Run k-means clustering on vending machine locations
    k <- 8 # Number of clusters to create
    set.seed(123)
    vm_clusters <- kmeans(vm_data[,c("lon", "lat")], centers = k, nstart = 25)

    # Add cluster information to original data
    vm_data$cluster <- as.factor(vm_clusters$cluster)

    # Visualize clustering results on a map
    vm_map <- get_googlemap(center = "Country", zoom = 11)
    ggmap(vm_map) + 
      geom_point(data = vm_data, aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = cluster), size = 1, stroke = 1) + 
      scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple", "brown", "grey",             "black")) +
      labs(title = "Vending Machine Clusters")

    # View summary statistics of each cluster
    cluster_summary <- vm_data %>%
      group_by(cluster) %>%
      summarise(num_vms = n(), total_sales = sum(SALES))
    print(cluster_summary)
```

The result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrNLR.png)

I've tried looking at the problem from a redistricting approach initially but it seems like clustering is the way to go. Furthermore, I've taken a look at trying out dbscans but it does not produce clusters (perhaps I did not adjust the parameters well enough).

I'm not sure how to add in the above constraints. I appreciate any and all help/suggestions.

Comment: Notice that the `kmeans` uses the euclidean distance instead of the geodesic distances. Also there is no constraint on number of elements per group. You should consider a simple clustering implementation that looks like kmeans, but uses the geodesic distance instead of the euclidean distance

Comment: @onyambu Ah, i see. Are there any specific R packages/links regarding this implementation that you could refer me to? Thanks!

Comment: Kmeans is a simple thing to implement. Start by using the euclidean distance, then see how to invoke the geodesic distance. Am sure the kmeans code will be less than 10 lines of code.

Comment: The scclust R package on CRAN can handle size and type constraints.  Bin the sales into categories/types.

Comment: *"I'm pretty new to R and adapted code from ChatGPT to accomplish this thus far."* ChatGPT doesn't have any code-writing logic. It's a word predictor. It read lots and lots of things off the internet and is trying to predict the next word. The "code" is spurts out is assembled from fragments of code it read off the internet, stitched together by wild guesses. Occasionally the code is correct, but most often it is completely wrong, and debugging it and making sure it works actually takes more effort than writing your own code.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Are there any beginner tutorials regarding this? I can't seem to understand what they're saying in the documentation.

Comment: @Stef Very true, spent a few nights trying to get the code to work.

Comment: `sc_clustering` is the main function.  Try the examples on its help page and make small modifications to them until it is clear.  Also see the README file.

Comment: Since you said you are new ro R, you can attend my R classes to learn more bout R. You will learn how to implement these type of problems. Question is how patient are you.

Comment: Just add those two features to your defined dataset.